# Extend Wi-Fi on a non-Apple network by Ethernet with an Airport Express

Tags: airport, airplay, ethernet

Can I extend Wi-Fi on a non-Apple network by Ethernet with an Airport Express as well as utilize Airplay?

I want to run an Ethernet cable to an Airport Express from a non-Apple router, set the Airport Express as Wi-Fi extender with same network credentials as the main router connected by Ethernet.

The main purpose will be to get the audio out on the Airport  Express to an amplifier so I can reliably stream music via AirPlay.

Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is yes.**

Apple has an excellent support document -   [Wi-Fi base stations: Extending the range of your wireless network by adding additional Wi-Fi base stations](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202056).

Basically, what you're looking to do is connect via the Ethernet ports one or more AirPort (Express, Extreme, or Capsule) to an existing router or gateway.  See the image below.

[image]

Once you've configured your AirPorts WiFi settings to match your existing WiFi network you will be able to stream to any of the AirPort devices you have setup.  The [Airport Setup Guide](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1613/en_US/airport_express_80211n_2nd_gen_setup_guide.pdf) has further details on this.

> If you connect AirPort Express to your stereo or powered speakers, you
>   can use AirPlay to play music from iTunes on any computer or from an
>   iOS device on your network.